# java: Printing sorted arrayList is giving me IndexOutofBoundsException

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

This is my Scheduler Class that sorts the arraylist. I made a custom compareTo method that returns an int value of 1, -1 or 0.

```
private ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();


public Scheduler(ArrayList<Event> events){


    for (int i=0; i<events.size(); i++)
    {
        this.events.add(events.get(i));

    }

} 

public ArrayList<Event> getSchedule(){
    int i;
    int j;
    int N = events.size();


        for (i = 0; i <=(N-1); i++)
    {
        for(j = 1; j <= N;j++)
        {

    if(events.get(i).getEndTime().compareTo(events.get(j).getEndTime()) > 0){
                Collections.swap(events, i, j);
            }
        }   
    }

    return events;
}
```

I call it later in my UI class

Scheduler s = new Scheduler(events);

```
        System.out.println("Schedule:");

    for(int i = 0; i<s.getSchedule().size(); i++){
        System.out.println(s.getSchedule().get(i)); 
        }
```

It's giving me an IndexOutofBoundError. Why is it giving me this error, and how can I fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: for (i = 0; i <=(N-1); i++) change to for (i = 0; i <(N-1); i++)

Answer (score 0):

In your `getSchedule()` method you are iterating `i` to `N-1` and `j` to `N` with `N` being the size of the list. A list of `n` objects has the indexes `0 to n-1`, so when accessing index `n` you try to access the data after the last element of the list which gives you an `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

A quick solution might be to set `N` to another value, which should be `size - 1`:

```
int N = events.size() - 1;
```

**Even better:** if you implemented a custom `compareTo()` method then you can implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and then just use [`Collections.sort(events)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) instead of sorting the events yourself.

Comment: ok, changing the N got rid of the indexoutbounds error. But I realized that I have a problem in my compareTo method. 

`public int compareTo(Time that){ 
if(this.getHour() < that.getHour())
    { return 1; } 
else if(this.getHour() > that.getHour())
    { return -1; }
else{ if(this.getMinute() < that.getMinute())
    { return 1; } 
else if(this.getMinute() > that.getMinute())
     { return -1; }  
    
     return 0; }` 

This is preventing me from swapping since no matter what it will return the default value. Seems like an easy fix, but i cant get it

Comment: I tried some similar code and it seemed to work. The only thing I see in your code is that `compareTo` should return a negative value when `this` is lesser than `that` (according to Java 8 Javadoc). Did you yet debug through the `compareTo` method?